# NoSuchAlgorithmException when using aSmack 0.8.3 for XMPP chat application

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I have included the logcat output. Please help me resolve this issue.

> 08-09 11:06:32.762: WARN/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(883):
>   setKernelCountSet(10012, 0) failed with errno -2
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):
>   java.security.KeyStoreException:
>   ava.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not
>   found
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):    at
>   java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:119)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.(ServerTrustManager.java:70)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:871)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:221)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567): Caused by:
>   java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation
>   not found
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     at
>   java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:116)
>
> 08-09 11:06:32.856: WARN/System.err(1567):     ... 5 more

---

here is the logcat message iam getting now after adding ur code..

```
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733):     at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733):     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:71)
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:871)
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:221)
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
08-09 11:35:34.469: WARN/System.err(1733):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
```

---

Its not referring any line in my code...

```
08-09 11:57:32.126: W/BackupManagerService(868): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.providers.settings' uid=1001
08-09 11:57:32.147: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(868): setKernelCountSet(10012, 0) failed with errno -2
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497):     at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497):     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:71)
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:871)
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:221)
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
08-09 11:57:32.198: W/System.err(1497):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
```

Comment: on which version you are trying run?

Comment: I am trying on 4.0.3 ICS emulator

Comment: check the edited code in my answer

Comment: which server you are trying to connect to? your local server?

Comment: iam trying to connect to talk.google.com.....I am following this tutorial ..  http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Building-a-Chat-Application

Comment: Probably the asmack library you are using is causing the problem, try using the latest one from here http://asmack.freakempire.de/

It is working for me with the latest library

Comment: the jar iam using now(asmack-android-17-0.8.3) seems to be the latest one...

Comment: I think that is a warning..you might be execute your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I handle it

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("your_server", port_no);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
    config.setTruststorePassword(null);
    config.setTruststorePath(null);
} else {
    config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
    String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
    if (path == null)
        path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
            + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
            + "cacerts.bks";
    config.setTruststorePath(path);
}
```

Comment: @lingareddyk which message?

Comment: its posted as my answer...i could not add it as a comment